# Find out print size of HPGL (.plt) file programmatically

Tags: plot, debian, printers

I'm currently working on a project where I have to find out the print size of HPGL(2) files which usually come with a ".plt" file extension.

I'm running a Unix system with Debian (PHP) and tried out "hp2xx" already which worked fine for some files but had problems detecting the size of more complex print files.

Is there any other method on finding out the print size of HPGL files?
Maybe someone already has some experiences.

Answer (score 1):

hp2xx gets font sizes hilariously wrong, so if you have LB commands, it will produce misleading output.

CERN's free [HP-GL Viewer](http://service-hpglview.web.cern.ch/service-hpglview/hpglviewer.html) has a `-size` option that spits out drawing extents.